# How do I get Jupyter Notebook to display Kernel, Widgets, Python 3 at the top?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I created a file on my local directory for a new Jupyter Notebook. I saved the file in Notepad with an ipnyb file extension.  I opened it up, did a git bash here.  In the (anaconda) terminal I did source activate PythonData.  Then I typed Jupityer Notebook to open it up in Jupyter Notebook.

There are many fields at the top missing including Kernal, Widgets Python 3.  Does anyone know how to get those added to the Jupityer Notebook?

Additionally if you know how to section it off like the second image below, that would be super helpful too.   Mine is a huge white open section, while the notebook I want to have is sectioned off into chunks.

[How it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbIY1.png)

[How I wish to have Jupyter Notebook look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0ljD.png)

Comment: Could you please describe, how you installed Jupyter (what OS are you using, what version of anaconda, what did you type to get jupyter).  Also, you can use backtics ` to highlight code, like `source activate PythonData`.

Answer (score 1):

Your ipython file does not recognize as Notebook.
[image]

In your Jupiter home page go to new tab and create a new Notebook[image]

For more reference here are default notebook file structure

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```